# Проблема с дефолтным методом File.delete()

Tags: java, junit

*Делаю небольшой проект - база данных резюме с разными реализациями хранилищ. Проблема возникла при реализации хранилищ через File с сохранением и чтением из файла. Проходит 1 тест, а дальше программа падает с исключением при удалении файла. При этом мой метод delete() реализован через дефолтный File.delete(). Он же используется при очистке всего хранилища с резюме.*
Вот эти методы:

```
@Override
protected void deleteResume(File file) {
    if (!file.delete()) {
        throw new StorageException("File delete error", file.getName());
    }
}

@Override
protected void clearStorage() {
    for (File file : Objects.requireNonNull(directory.listFiles())) {
        deleteResume(file);
    }
}
```

Здесь весь проект с тестами: [https://github.com/JavaSash/baseJava](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfWYu.png)

**Вкратце что там происходит:**

1. Общий класс с основными методами находится в параметризованном `AbstractStorage<SK>`, от него наследуется частная реализация сохранения резюме в файл и чтение из файла - `FileStorage extends AbstractStorage<File>`. Он реализован через паттерн стратегия. В него передаём директорию типа `File` и, собственно, файл стратегии `StrategySwitcher switcher` (класс находится в пакете `Strategy`).
2. В классе FileStorage и находятся методы `deleteResume()` и `clearStorage()`, который внутри использует `deleteResume()`. deleteResume() использует дефолтный метод класса File, который возвращает boolean и если файл не удалён, то бросает исключение.
3. В тестах структура аналогичная: родительский абстрактный класс `AbstractStorageTest` с тестами, в который через конструктор и `super()` передаём объект нужного нам хранилища (`FileStorage`).

   ```
   public FileStorageTest() throws IllegalAccessException {
       super(new FileStorage(STORAGE_DIR, new StrategySwitcher()));
   }
   ```
4. Перед каждым тестом делаем setup: чистим хранилище резюме (через `clearStorage()` и сохраняем 3 резюме). При запуске тестов проходит updateNotExist:
   [image: Успешно прошёл тест updateNotExist]

И на следующем тесте delete падает:
[image: Метод deleteResume() не удалил файл]

Дебагом упёрся в то, что почему-то не проходит метод с вызовом дефолтного `File.delete()`.

Метод clearStorage() удаляет все файлы в пакете, кроме файлов резюме. Значит возможно проблема ещё при записи может быть.
Первый тест проходит возможно потому, что при сетапе чистим пустое хранилище.

**В чём может быть проблема?**

Comment: По той части кода, что показан - ничего сказать нельзя. Поставьте точку останова в `setUp` и при втором заходе туда (т.е. перед вторым тестом) проверьте, существует ли файл, тот который пробуете удалить.

Answer (score 0):

Для того, чтобы вызов file.delete() вернул true, необходимо, чтобы файл существовал, а если это директория, чтобы она была не пустая, об этом сказано в [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#delete--).

Попробуйте удалить файл с помощью `Files.delete(file.toPath())` (из пакета java.nio), вы получите более [конкретную](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/delete.html) ошибку.